# Can't run this script to display results on website

Tags: python, web, bluetooth

I would like a web interface to retrieve data from lithium LifePo4 batteries on my boat.

On a raspberry with Raspbian, I have write a program to retreive bluetooth data from a battery BMS such SOC, current, and ohter datas, this code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# The line above ^ is important. Don't leave it out. It should be at the
# top of the file.

import cgi, cgitb # Not used, but will be needed later.

from dalybms import DalyBMSBluetooth
import asyncio


class DalyBMSConnection():
    def __init__(self, mac_address):
        self.bt_bms = DalyBMSBluetooth()
        self.mac_address = mac_address

    async def connect(self):
        await self.bt_bms.connect(mac_address=self.mac_address)

    async def update_cell_voltages(self):
        cell_voltages = await self.bt_bms.get_cell_voltages()

    async def update_cell_voltage_range(self):
        cell_v_range = await self.bt_bms.get_cell_voltage_range()
        print(cell_v_range)

    async def update_status(self):
        status = await self.bt_bms.get_status()
        print(status)


    async def update_mosfet(self):
        mosfet = await self.bt_bms.get_mosfet_status()
        print(mosfet)

    async def update_soc(self):
        soc = await self.bt_bms.get_soc()
        print(soc)

    async def update_temps(self):
        temps = await self.bt_bms.get_temperatures()
        print(temps)

    async def update_bal(self):
        bal = await self.bt_bms.get_balancing_status()
        print(bal)

    async def update_errors(self):
        errors = await self.bt_bms.get_errors()
        print(errors)

async def main(con):
    await con.connect()
    await con.update_status()
    await con.update_soc()
    await con.update_cell_voltage_range()
    await con.update_mosfet()
    await con.update_bal()
    await con.update_errors()
    await con.bt_bms.disconnect()



con = DalyBMSConnection(mac_address='C7:7C:03:06:0F:03')
asyncio.run(main(con))
```

and my server.py:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        CGIHTTPRequestHandler.cgi_directories = ['/cgi-bin']

        httpd = HTTPServer(('', 8000),             # localhost:8000
                           CGIHTTPRequestHandler)  # CGI support.

        print(f"Running server. Use [ctrl]-c to terminate.")

        httpd.serve_forever()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(f"\nReceived keyboard interrupt. Shutting down server.")
        httpd.socket.close()
```

My problem: I have a loading blank screen

Can you help me ?

Comment: try adding print("Content-type: text/html\n\n") before asyncio.run